# Update multiple columns with different criteria for each column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

In the student table, I have 'null' and ('') empty cells. Is there a way to update multiple columns by using different criteria for each column?

[image]

Already, I have tried a few queries like below but those did not go as planned

1st:

```
update student_info SET email_id = Null, department = NULL, scholarship = NULL WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT email_id,department,scholarship from student_info WHERE 
(email_id in ('null','') or department in ('null', '') or scholarship in ('null', '')));
GO
```

2nd:

```
UPDATE student_info SET 
        email_id = CASE  WHEN ( email_id in ('null','')) THEN NULL END,
        department = CASE WHEN (department in ('null','')) THEN NULL END,
        scholarship = CASE WHEN (scholarship in ('null','')) THEN NULL END,
        location = CASE WHEN (location in ('null','')) THEN NULL END
        GO
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE student_info ( student_id INT, email_id varchar(15), scholarship 
VARCHAR(5),location varchar(20), department VARCHAR(15), phone varchar(15));
GO
```

Value:

```
INSERT INTO student_info 
VALUES 
(1002,'1002@uni.com', 'Yes', 'null','', '+00000002'),
(1003,'null', 'Yes', 'International','', '+00000003'),
(1004,'1004@uni.com', 'null', '','English', '+00000004'),
(1005,'null', 'Yes', 'Domestic','', '+00000005'),
(1006,'null', 'Yes', 'Domestic','English', ''),
(1007,'', 'Yes', 'Domestic','English', '+00000007'),
(1009,'1001@uni.com', 'null', 'Domestic','English', '+00000009');
 GO
```

Comment: `NULL` is not the same as `'NULL'`. What is the actual value in the column? Also what is your expected output?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "case when" option is missing the "ELSE" and "WHERE":

I added the 2 and it works ([sqlfiddle to see the result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4d561/5)):

```
UPDATE student_info SET 
        email_id = (CASE  WHEN ( email_id in ('null','')) THEN NULL ELSE email_id END),
        department = (CASE WHEN (department in ('null','')) THEN NULL ELSE department END),
        scholarship = (CASE WHEN (scholarship in ('null','')) THEN NULL ELSE scholarship END),
        location = (CASE WHEN (location in ('null','')) THEN NULL ELSE location END)
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT email_id,department,scholarship from student_info WHERE 
(email_id in ('null','') or department in ('null', '') or scholarship in ('null', '')));
```

Comment: Now it's working. I think the "WHERE EXISTS" clause is not necessary here. I tried without it and It's working fine. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The `exists` subquery checks if _any_ row needs to be updated. Since it is not a [correlated subquery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver15#correlated) it does not restrict which rows are processed by the `update`, it simply controls whether or not the _entire_ table is updated. There is also no reason to have a multi-column _select list_ (`email_id,department,scholarship`) in an `exists` subquery. It is only a placeholder required by the syntax and can be replaced by `NULL` or `1 / 0`. I prefer `42`.

Answer (score 3):

I think this would be more simply written as:

```
UPDATE student_info 
    SET email_id = (CASE WHEN email_id NOT IN ('null', '') THEN email_id END),
        department = (CASE WHEN (department NOT IN ('null', '') THEN department END),
        scholarship = (CASE WHEN scholarship NOT ('null', '') THEN scholarship END),
        location = (CASE WHEN location NOT IN ('null', '') THEN location END)
WHERE email_id IN ('null', '') OR
      department IN ('null', '') OR
      scholarship IN ('null', '') OR
      location IN ('null', '');
```

The changes are:

1. The `CASE` expressions now return column when there is *no* match.  The missing `ELSE` means that matches are always `NULL`.
2. The `WHERE` clause does not use a subquery.  That is totally unnecessary.
3. The `WHERE` clause checks for all four columns.

In SQL Server, it is a good idea to use a `WHERE` clause to filter out records where there would be no changes.  SQL Server "does the update" even when there are no changes to the record.

Comment: @Rahat . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?  Subquery in the `WHERE` clause is not the best solution to your problem.